# How to add scrollbar only for table data

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table format in my module. I want to add scrollbar only for my table data not for the whole table. How can I add? Please look at the below jsfiddle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zzhydLn/)

```css
/*
 Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
 This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
 and also iPads specifically.
 */
 @media
 only screen and (max-width: 760px),
 (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
   display: block;
  }

  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  thead tr {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
  }

  tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

  td {
   /* Behave  like a "row" */
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
   position: relative;
   padding-left: 50%;
  }

  td:before {
   /* Now like a table header */
   position: absolute;
   /* Top/left values mimic padding */
   top: 6px;
   left: 6px;
   width: 45%;
   padding-right: 10px;
   white-space: nowrap;
  }

  /*
  Label the data
  */
  td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
  td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
  td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
  td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Favorite Color"; }
  td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Wars of Trek?"; }
  td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Porn Name"; }
  td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
  td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Dream Vacation City"; }
  td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "GPA"; }
  td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Arbitrary Data"; }
 }

 /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen
 and (min-device-width : 320px)
 and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   width: 320px; }
  }

 /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  body {
   width: 495px;
  }
 }



* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 #demo-top-bar {
  text-align: left;
  background: #222;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  width: 100% !important;
  z-index: 6000;
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
 }
 #demo-bar-inside {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 #demo-bar-buttons {
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: right;
 }
 #demo-bar-buttons a {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: white;
  margin: 2px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif !important;
 }
 #demo-bar-buttons a:hover,
 #demo-bar-buttons a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
 }
 #demo-bar-badge {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 302px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 #demo-bar-badge a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(/images/examples-logo.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
 }
 #demo-bar-badge:before, #demo-bar-badge:after {
  display: none !important;
 }

* { 
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
}
body { 
 font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, Serif; 
}
#page-wrap {
 margin: 50px;
}
p {
 margin: 20px 0; 
}

 /* 
 Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
 */
 table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
 }
 /* Zebra striping */
 tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #eee; 
 }
 th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
 }
 td, th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
 }
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">

 <table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>First Name</th>
   <th>Last Name</th>
   <th>Job Title</th>
   <th>Favorite Color</th>
   <th>Wars or Trek?</th>
   <th>Porn Name</th>
   <th>Date of Birth</th>
   <th>Dream Vacation City</th>
   <th>GPA</th>
   <th>Arbitrary Data</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>James</td>
   <td>Matman</td>
   <td>Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
   <td>Lettuce Green</td>
   <td>Trek</td>
   <td>Digby Green</td>
   <td>January 13, 1979</td>
   <td>Gotham City</td>
   <td>3.1</td>
   <td>RBX-12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The</td>
    <td>Tick</td>
    <td>Crimefighter Sorta</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>Wars</td>
    <td>John Smith</td>
    <td>July 19, 1968</td>
    <td>Athens</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>Edlund, Ben (July 1996).</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jokey</td>
    <td>Smurf</td>
    <td>Giving Exploding Presents</td>
    <td>Smurflow</td>
    <td>Smurf</td>
    <td>Smurflane Smurfmutt</td>
    <td>Smurfuary Smurfteenth, 1945</td>
    <td>New Smurf City</td>
    <td>4.Smurf</td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cindy</td>
    <td>Beyler</td>
    <td>Sales Representative</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>Wars</td>
    <td>Lori Quivey</td>
    <td>July 5, 1956</td>
    <td>Paris</td>
    <td>3.4</td>
    <td>3451</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Captain</td>
    <td>Cool</td>
    <td>Tree Crusher</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>Wars</td>
    <td>Steve 42nd</td>
    <td>December 13, 1982</td>
    <td>Las Vegas</td>
    <td>1.9</td>
    <td>Under the couch</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

In this fiddle, The table format is like this,
[image]

In this how can I add scrollbar for table data. I want the below format.
[image]

Comment: You can use nanoscroller for that. Here's a link [click here](https://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/)

Comment: At what screensize do you want to use the scrolling option it seems that at a screensize of 760px you are changing the behaviour of the table to appear as separate blocks.

Comment: HI shameem-ahmed, If I use nanoscroller, The whole table is scrolling. I just want to add scrollbar only in table data(tbody).

Answer (score 1):

Give an ID to the table, add a fixed height and `overflow:auto` as follows :

```css
#tableScroll
{
  height:300px;
  overflow:auto;
}

/*
 Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
 This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
 and also iPads specifically.
 */
 @media
 only screen and (max-width: 760px),
 (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

  /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
  table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
   display: block;
  }

  /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
  thead tr {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
  }

  tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

  td {
   /* Behave  like a "row" */
   border: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
   position: relative;
   padding-left: 50%;
  }

  td:before {
   /* Now like a table header */
   position: absolute;
   /* Top/left values mimic padding */
   top: 6px;
   left: 6px;
   width: 45%;
   padding-right: 10px;
   white-space: nowrap;
  }

  /*
  Label the data
  */
  td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
  td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
  td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
  td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Favorite Color"; }
  td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Wars of Trek?"; }
  td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Porn Name"; }
  td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
  td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Dream Vacation City"; }
  td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "GPA"; }
  td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Arbitrary Data"; }
 }

 /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen
 and (min-device-width : 320px)
 and (max-device-width : 480px) {
  body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   width: 320px; }
  }

 /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  body {
   width: 495px;
  }
 }



* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }
 #demo-top-bar {
  text-align: left;
  background: #222;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  width: 100% !important;
  z-index: 6000;
  padding: 20px 0 20px;
 }
 #demo-bar-inside {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
 #demo-bar-buttons {
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: right;
 }
 #demo-bar-buttons a {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: white;
  margin: 2px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif !important;
 }
 #demo-bar-buttons a:hover,
 #demo-bar-buttons a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
 }
 #demo-bar-badge {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 302px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  background-color: transparent !important;
 }
 #demo-bar-badge a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 0;
  bottom: auto;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(/images/examples-logo.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -9999px;
 }
 #demo-bar-badge:before, #demo-bar-badge:after {
  display: none !important;
 }

* { 
 margin: 0; 
 padding: 0; 
}
body { 
 font: 14px/1.4 Georgia, Serif; 
}
#page-wrap {
 margin: 50px;
}
p {
 margin: 20px 0; 
}

 /* 
 Generic Styling, for Desktops/Laptops 
 */
 table { 
  width: 100%; 
  border-collapse: collapse; 
 }
 /* Zebra striping */
 tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
  background: #eee; 
 }
 th { 
  background: #333; 
  color: white; 
  font-weight: bold; 
 }
 td, th { 
  padding: 6px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  text-align: left; 
 }
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">

 <table id="tableScroll">
  <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>First Name</th>
   <th>Last Name</th>
   <th>Job Title</th>
   <th>Favorite Color</th>
   <th>Wars or Trek?</th>
   <th>Porn Name</th>
   <th>Date of Birth</th>
   <th>Dream Vacation City</th>
   <th>GPA</th>
   <th>Arbitrary Data</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>James</td>
   <td>Matman</td>
   <td>Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
   <td>Lettuce Green</td>
   <td>Trek</td>
   <td>Digby Green</td>
   <td>January 13, 1979</td>
   <td>Gotham City</td>
   <td>3.1</td>
   <td>RBX-12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The</td>
    <td>Tick</td>
    <td>Crimefighter Sorta</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>Wars</td>
    <td>John Smith</td>
    <td>July 19, 1968</td>
    <td>Athens</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>Edlund, Ben (July 1996).</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jokey</td>
    <td>Smurf</td>
    <td>Giving Exploding Presents</td>
    <td>Smurflow</td>
    <td>Smurf</td>
    <td>Smurflane Smurfmutt</td>
    <td>Smurfuary Smurfteenth, 1945</td>
    <td>New Smurf City</td>
    <td>4.Smurf</td>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cindy</td>
    <td>Beyler</td>
    <td>Sales Representative</td>
    <td>Red</td>
    <td>Wars</td>
    <td>Lori Quivey</td>
    <td>July 5, 1956</td>
    <td>Paris</td>
    <td>3.4</td>
    <td>3451</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Captain</td>
    <td>Cool</td>
    <td>Tree Crusher</td>
    <td>Blue</td>
    <td>Wars</td>
    <td>Steve 42nd</td>
    <td>December 13, 1982</td>
    <td>Las Vegas</td>
    <td>1.9</td>
    <td>Under the couch</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: yeah works if you look at the table in small (mobile) view but not on the desktop version

Comment: I have put it out of all media queries, it shall work for all view-ports, it works for me on desktop also.

Comment: Yeah its for me on mobile view. But not in desktop. If I put it out of all media queries also, its not working